# How do I manually trigger a specific app's share extension?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-extensions

When I share a file via iOS' `UIActivityViewController`, I can press the "More" button and see a bunch of apps that I can send my file to. My question is: how can I add a button in my app that would send a file specifically to one of these apps (provided that it's installed of course)? Like a "Send to Slack" button or something like that.

Please note that I am not asking how to show a `UIActivityViewController`, that's working just fine. I want to programmatically send a file to one of the apps that are listed in the `UIActivityViewController`'s Apps that can receive said file.

[image] [image]

Comment: Check out [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/).